# How to sanitize or bind html in Ionic Wordpress app

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this code for socialsharing in ionic wordpress app and all this `this.post.excerpt.rendered, this.post.title.rendered, this.post.images.large, this.post.link` are called from a database using JSON restapi

```
sharePost() {

    this.socialSharing.share(this.post.excerpt.rendered, this.post.title.rendered, this.post.images.large, this.post.link)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("sharePost: Success");
    }).catch(() => {
      console.error("sharePost: failed");
    });

  }
```

This codes outputs something like this

```
Catering &#038; Cleaning Services 
<p>Some text[&hellip;]</p>
http://www.example.com/home.jpg
http://www.example.com/home.html
```

I want the code to deal with the html special characters and display something like:

```
Catering & Cleaning Services 
Some text[...]
http://www.example.com/home.jpg
http://www.example.com/home.html
```

Comment: You could try using `trustAsHtml` for each of the texts, such as `trustAsHtml(this.post.excerpt.rendered)`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have tried it like this `this.socialSharing.share(trustAsHtml(this.post.title.rendered),`  and its giving an error `Cannot find name 'trustAsHtml'.`